# how to use requests.session so that headers are presevred and reused in subsequent get requests

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I might have misunderstood the `requests.session` object.

```
headers ={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.28 Safari/537.36'}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://www.barchart.com/', headers = headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

This works fine and return `200` as expected.

However this following return `403` and shows that the headers from the first request have not been saved in the session like it would manually using a browser:

```
headers ={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.28 Safari/537.36'}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://www.barchart.com/', headers = headers)
r = s.get('https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/CLQ20')
print(r.status_code)
print(s.headers)
```

I thought there would be a way to compound headers, cookies etc from 1 requests to the other using the session object... am i wrong ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `session.headers` ([doc](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.headers)) property to specify headers that are sent with each request:

```
import requests

headers ={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.28 Safari/537.36'}

s = requests.session()
s.headers = headers       # <-- set default headers here

r = s.get('https://www.barchart.com/')
print(r.status_code)
print(s.headers)
print('-' * 80)
r = s.get('https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/CLQ20')
print(r.status_code)
print(s.headers)

s.close()
```

Prints:

```
200
{'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.28 Safari/537.36'}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
200
{'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.28 Safari/537.36'}
```

Comment: Thx Andrej, but what i would like is that the session headers keep the cookies that are set by the website... How is that possible ??

Comment: @jimbasquiat session keeps the cookies, try to `print(s.cookies)` after each request to see it.

Comment: But how can i preserve the full headers just like a manual browser would ?? I have the issue of a x-xsrf-token that somehow is set by the site in google chrome, and i need to be able to reproduce that with requests, if possible...

Comment: @jimbasquiat Sometimes the cookies are set by Javascript - so you need to set the cookies manually (requests doesn't execute javascript), for example `s.cookies['x-xsrf-token'] = ...`

Comment: Yes but here the x-xsrf-token is appended directly to the header, as well as in the cookie. The cookie seems to be set fine... So it doesnt seem like its a javascript issue. The issue is just that the session only preserve the cookie but not the headers.. Is there no way to do that ? I mean so far i was recreating the x-xsrf token manually but this is quite a fragile solution and hard to debug. That is why i am looking for a more definitive solution that just does what a manual browser does with `requests`

Comment: @jimbasquiat I'm afraid no, `requests` doesn't modify headers automatically, you need to set them up manually. Only cookies are set automatically.